# How to implement custom object like NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I want to implement an object named "XXXList" which will return a collection (not NSArray subclass), so that I can use it like an NSArray:

```
XXXList *list = [XXXList list];

for(id object in list)
{
    ......
}
```

Comment: where will `XXXList` will store values? if not array then how?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, obviously an object that implements the NSFastEnumeration protocol…

Comment: @ikinciviking: I agree. But I would like to know how can I create a set of objects which are not arrays/set/dictionary. HOw to `add:`, `remove:` etc.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: in the context of this question that is irrelevant.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya (Short answer: You could build a data structure (array or linked list) with pure C constructs and then create an objective-c wrapper class around that.) I think you pose a valid question. Why don’t you try to open a new one?

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert: Hehe, No I am quite comfortable with all collection classes. No need to try for a new-custom collection class.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya So when you wrote “But I would *like to know how* can I create a set of objects which are not arrays/set/dictionary […]”, you actually meant you didn’t want to know anything?

Comment: Yes, I thought there would be something that i am unaware of. Using C-array and creating a linked-list will be tedious, and we will loose all the given API's of arr/dict/set isn't it?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya As I said: you should open a new question. Discussion in the comments is discouraged. Fundamentally, you don’t have to lose anything; since this is how all the NS… collection classes are implemented under the hood, it is certainly possible to exactly replicate their behaviour, you’ll just have to do it yourself. There are certainly good use cases for this (trading power for performance, for example).

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you can do with `NSArray`s, I’ll list the two of them that I think might be what you’re after:

Firstly you can iterate with a `for…in` loop ([NSFastEnumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html)), secondly you can use the indexed subscript notation (something like `list[2]`). Fortunately, both of these are available for other types of objects as well, you just need to implement them.

Implementing NSFastEnumeration isn’t so trivial, I’d suggest reading up on [Mike Ash’s NSBlog post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-16-implementing-fast-enumeration.html).

Implementing subscript notation on the other hand is quite simple, there are just two methods you need to implement.

There’s the getter:

```
 - (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript: (NSUInteger)index;
```

and the setter

```
 - (void)setObject: (id)obj atIndexedSubscript: (NSUInteger)index;
```

There’s an [NSBlog post on that](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html), too.

Comment: OP says : "no nsarray and its subclass"

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I know, that’s why I listed two ways for objects to start behaving like NSArrays even though they’re not.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, an object does not need to be an array to be enumeratable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [NSFastEnumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html) if you want to use your own classes.